# Float and margin CSS

Tags: html, css

I've created five different sections of images, displayed just as you can see in jsfiddle, the problem is that I can't control the margin of these imagesections. The thing is that I'm trying to add some space between section 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5, but whenever I add the margin the section just refuse to move.
I've tried to reset the float with the codes:

```
clear:both;
```

and

```
float: none;
```

but without success. The result of those codes is just that the section jumps to a new line.

The fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p0eaxkpz/

Comment: I've tried adding `margin: 20px;` to both `.imagesection1` and `.image1`, it worked.

Comment: Can you then add space between imagesection 2/3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your problem, there is an error in your code: `margin-left:0,5%;` should be `margin-left:0.5%;`

Here is your updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p0eaxkpz/2/)

I have simply added `margin: 0; padding: 0;` to all elements, you can see it's working well. Basically, there is no need for you to wrap the images with `<section>` tags.

Comment: Trust me, I have tried that. If we could focus more on to shrink the giant space between imagesection 1/2, that would be great.

Comment: Thanks! I had added * margin, padding: 0, thought I did not have to use it again.

Answer (score 0):

I also got [a more modular aproach](https://jsfiddle.net/p0eaxkpz/3/)

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
body
{
 background-color:black;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 padding-bottom:20%;
 
}

#wrapper

{
 width:80%;
 height:1000px;
 background-color:white;
 margin:auto;
 
 
 
 }

#headerloga
{
 float:left;
 width:20%;
 height:20%;
 font-family: "Gotham Medium";
 font-weight:800;
 font-size:40px;
 padding-top:10%;
 padding-left:10%;
 
 
 
 }
 
 #menu
 
 {
  float:left;
  width:60%;
  height:auto;
  font-family:"Gotham Medium";
  font-size:15px;
  padding-top:17.5%;
  padding-left:10%;
  

  }
  
  ul {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

a {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 0.2em 0.6em;
 
}

a:hover {
    color:#ED1C91;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}

#imageshosting {
 background-color:#CCC;
 width:60%;
 height:80%;
 position:absolute;
 clear:both;
 top:40%;
 left:18%;
}

.img-hosted {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    height:49%;
    margin:0.5%
}

.w33 {
    width:32.33%;
}
.w66 {
    width:65.66%;
}
.img-nextline {
    clear: both;
}


#foot {
 background-color:#666;
 clear:both;
 position:absolute;
 top:120%;
 left:18%;
 width:60%;
 height:10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"><!-- Webpage wrapper-->


<div id="headerloga">
Test
Test2
<section style="color:#ED178C; ">Test3 </section>
</div>
<div id="menu"><!--Menu-->
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">KUNDER</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">GAMLA FAVORITER</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">OM OSS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">KONST</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">KONTAKT</a></li>

</ul>
</div><!-- End of menu-->

<!-- images starts-->
<div id="imageshosting">
<img class="img-hosted w33" src="images/testimage1.jpg"/>
<img class="img-hosted w33" src="images/testimage2.jpg"/>
<img class="img-hosted w33" src="images/testimage3.jpg"/>

<!-- New image line -->

<img class="img-hosted w66 img-nextline" src="images/testimage4.jpg"/>
<img class="img-hosted w33" src="images/testimage5.jpg"/>


</div><!--Imageshosting ends-->

<!--Footer here-->
<div id="foot">
<p>Hello</p>
</div>

</div><!-- End of webpage wrapper-->
```